# Format positive and negative decimal numbers with jquery and regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, currency, number-formatting

I found this code below at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lminervino/3useLpwd/) that, in my shitty opinion, is very nice. 
But it doesn't format negative numbers, only positive.
I tried to modify it but my regex knowledge wasn't enough.
Could anyone help me modify this to format positive and negative numbers?

```js
$('#valor').keyup(function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    v = v.replace(/\D/g,'');
    v = v.replace(/(\d{1,2})$/, ',$1');  
    v = v.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.');  
    v = v != '' ? 'R$ '+ v : '';
    $(this).val(v); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check and see if the value is negative when you start, and add the sign back in at the end:

```
$('#valor').keyup(function(){
    let v = $(this).val();
    const neg = v.startsWith('-');

    v = v.replace(/[-\D]/g,'');
    v = v.replace(/(\d{1,2})$/, ',$1');
    v = v.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.');

    v = v != ''?'$ '+v:'';
    if(neg) v = '-'.concat(v);  // prepend the dash

    $(this).val(v);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3useLpwd/95/)

---

EDIT: Here's a more "pure" regex solution:

```
$('#valor').keyup(function(){
    let v = $(this).val();

    v = v.replace(/[^-\d]/g, '');
    v = v.replace(/(\d{1,2})$/g, ',$1');
    v = v.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.');

    v = v ? '$ ' + v : '';
    $(this).val(v);

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3useLpwd/98/)

Basically, in the first replace statement, you add `'-'` to the set of characters to *not* get replaced, i.e. everything that isn't a digit or a dash will get replaced by `''` in this new version.

Comment: This solves the problem, but I wanted to know how to solve this with regex, because it looks like more elegant to me.